# What does "outweighed by" mean?

Tags: meaning

> We are allowed to use your personal information where it is in our
>   interests to do so, and those interests **aren't outweighed by any
>   potential prejudice to you**. (https://beam.org/privacy)
>
> To drive commercial value for our shareholders, where
>   **not outweighed by any potential prejudice to you**.

What does "where not outweighed by any potential prejudice to you" mean? Does it mean that "where interests don't create any potential negative impact to you"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a metaphor. Think of it as a scale.

(Our interest: use of your personal information.) || (Your interest: Potential prejudice.)

Essentially, it's saying they have the right to use your personal information for their own benefit so long as it doesn't negatively impact you. (And they will weigh the pros and cons.)

Typically, the use of this information would be to sell it to marketing firms.

Of course, the statement is somewhat open to interpretation. What you consider to be a negative impact they may not care about. This is why many people will simply not agree to these terms—opting to not sign such a contract in the first place. Instead, they find a company with similar services which agrees to never disclose personal information at all.